# use timestamp type for line graph in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

im going to use time which saved in database table

```
$created_at = DB::table('posts')->select('created_at')->get();
```

this return Collection with this format

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1201 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => {#1209 ▼
      +"created_at": "2021-04-18 11:17:37"
    }
    1 => {#1208 ▼
      +"created_at": "2021-04-18 11:20:34"
```

now how can i filter just month ?

I need this for line graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve it

```
$created_at = Post::select(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as month'))->get();
```

If you want to get only simple array which is mostly we use in line graphs

```
$created_at = User::select(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as month'))->get();
$array  = [];
foreach($created_at as $month) {
  $array[] = $month->month;
}
dd($array);
```